# Tomcat 8.5.9 , using a windows service, does not start.but starts fine from bin\startup.bat

Tags: tomcat8

I have installed Tomcat8.5.9, while starting from bin\startup.bat, it starts fine. Asper my requirement I have to start it from a Windows service, which I have created using below config file.

While it does not have any exception in the log

************Configuration file ***********************

```
    # Java Application
    wrapper.java.command=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java.exe
    #HIBERNATE_HOME=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/hibernate/hibernate-distribution-    3.6.5.Final

    # The working directory for Tomcat
    wrapper.working.dir=${CATALINA_HOME}/bin

    # Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
    # needed starting from 1.  Note that folder names are case-sensitive.
    wrapper.java.classpath.1=.
    wrapper.java.classpath.2=${OCC_BASE}/run/*.jar
    # Due to possible incompatibilities between the log4j versions included in the following classpaths, this entry must come first.
    wrapper.java.classpath.3=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/log4j/apache-log4j-1.2.17/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.4=${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/bootstrap.jar
    #wrapper.java.classpath.4=${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/*.jar

    #Tuscany folder contains some jms classes used by log4j. Keep it for now, but should replace with just what's needed
    wrapper.java.classpath.5=${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.6=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/axis2-1.5.4/lib/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.7=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/tuscany-sca-1.4/lib/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.8=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/slf4j/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.9=${OCC_BASE}/config
    wrapper.java.classpath.10=${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/occ600webservice/WEB-INF/services/*.aar

    # For hibernate.
    wrapper.java.classpath.11=${OCC_BASE}/config/orm
    wrapper.java.classpath.12=${HIBERNATE_HOME}/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.13=${HIBERNATE_HOME}/lib/required/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.14=${HIBERNATE_HOME}/lib/optional/c3p0/*.jar
    # wrapper.java.classpath.13=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/hibernate/hibernate-distribution-3.6.5.Final/lib/optional/ehcache/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.15=${HIBERNATE_HOME}/lib/jpa/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.16=C:/Program Files/SQL Anywhere 11/Java/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.17=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/Sybase/jconnect/jConnect-6_0/classes/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.18=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/apache-shiro-1.2.2/*.jar
    wrapper.java.classpath.19=${OCC_BASE}/3rdparty/commons-beanutils-1.9.1/*.jar


    # Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
    wrapper.java.library.path.1=.

    # Java Additional Parameters
    # wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djavax.management.builder.initial=mx4j.server.MX4JMBeanServerBuilder
    wrapper.java.additional.1=-server
    wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dcatalina.home=${CATALINA_HOME}
    wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcatalina.base=${CATALINA_HOME}
    wrapper.java.additional.4=-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${CATALINA_HOME}/endorsed 
    wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djava.io.tmpdir=${CATALINA_HOME}/temp
    wrapper.java.additional.6=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 

    # We need to set the Java system property for the path to the OCC install too.  It is needed (at least) if
    # we want to use the variable in the log4j.properties file.
    wrapper.java.additional.7=-DOCC_BASE=${OCC_BASE}

    # Initial Java Heap Size (in MB) 
    wrapper.java.initmemory=128

    # Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
    wrapper.java.maxmemory=2048

    # Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
    wrapper.java.app.mainclass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
    wrapper.app.parameter.1=start

    # Port which the native wrapper code will attempt to connect to
    wrapper.port=0

    # Increase the ping timeout to avoid problems where 
    # the Wrapper thinks that the JVM is hung when it isn't if another process is taking 100% of the CPU for longer than 30 seconds
    wrapper.ping.timeout=600

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=${OCC_BASE}/logs/tomcat_svc.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
# the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
# of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
# 'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
# files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=2

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=ERROR

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper NT Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=Apache_Tomcat

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=Apache_Tomcat

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=The Apache Tomcat application server.

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=EMSOCC600DomainManager
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.2=EMSOCC600DAL

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=DEMAND_START

# Priority at which the service is run.  NORMAL, LOW, HIGH, or
# REALTIME
wrapper.ntservice.process_priority=NORMAL

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=true

wrapper.ntservice.additional.1 = -server

**************************
wrapper.daemonize=TRUE



***************LOG file output**********************

    11\Java\wstx-asl-3.2.6.jar;C:\EMS\OCC600\3rdparty\Sybase\jconnect\jConnect-6_0\classes\jconn3.jar;C:\EMS\OCC600\3rdparty\Sybase\jconnect\jConnect-6_0\classes\jTDS3.jar;C:\EMS\OCC600\3rdparty\apache-shiro-1.2.2\shiro-all-1.2.2.jar;C:\EMS\OCC600\3rdparty\commons-beanutils-1.9.1\commons-beanutils-1.9.1.jar
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:28|library path=.
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:28|Application args: no args
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:29|- Using "C:\EMS\OCC600\3rdparty\apache-tomcat-8.5.9\temp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:29|external stop false
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:29|args: 
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:29|start
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:29|count 0 1489164089256
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:29|Controller State: WAITING -> ESTABLISHED
    INFO|9448/0|17-03-10 16:41:29|Controller State: ESTABLISHED -> LOGGED_ON
```